# Uncaught ReferenceError: loaderOff is not defined at HTMLIFrameElement.onload

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, onload

I looked around but nothing helps here.
this is simple.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
...
<iframe onload="loaderOff()" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
...
...
<script>

  function loaderOn(){
    var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    loader.classList.remove('hide');
    main.classList.add("blur");
  }

  function loaderOff(){
    var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    loader.classList.add('hide');
    main.classList.remove("blur");
  }

  ...
  ...

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but i get,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: loaderOff is not defined at HTMLIFrameElement.onload
```

even though the function is working, but the error in console is there;
any help?

Comment: Is it possible, that the iframe loads before the script containing `loaderOff` function has been parsed? What exactly means "_the function is working_"?

Comment: no! after page already loads, and after filling some inputs, I come to it. @Teemu so page is already  loaded completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Teemu comment is right, I just tried with the `<script>` into `<head>` and it worked.

Comment: any idea though why is it like that. I would like to improve my understanding.